# Laravel generates an error "Echo is Echo is not defined"

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-echo

I am working with Laravel Event Broadcasting and i am using pusher driver for broadcasting event and its working perfectly.

The public channel is subscribed successfully from client side using pusher provided `js` library

```
var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_my_app_key', {
    encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('TestPusher');
    channel.bind('App\\Events\\TestPusher', function(data) {
alert(data.msg);
});
```

But when i use Echo in my client side code

```
Echo.channel('TestPusher')
    .listen('TestPusher', (e) => {
        console.log(e.msg, e.chatMessage);
    });
```

It generates the error " Echo is not defined ".

I already installed the Laravel Echo library using `npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js` in my application and also included the following code in `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` file as per the laravel provide documentation.

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_my_app_key'
});
```

So please help me how can i fix this problem.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-echo). You get spark to use it.

Comment: thanks @iDroid but i already tried this link but not working for me can you give me specific explanation about this ?

Comment: You should try using gulp to compile your assets if you have not already done so.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was not compiling `bootstrap.js` together with the rest of the code because I had removed the line `require('./bootstrap')` from `app.js`. I added that line back and I was home and dry.
[As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144745/error-echo-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a few days ago. My gulp installation was all messed up and Laravel versioning didn't help.

Sorry if this doesn't help, it's just my experience and most detailed as possible:

First, I'll consider you do have the js/app.js script included on you site.

Now, you're seeing this error because, as Josh mentioned, you're not compiling your js files. After editing 'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js', this file needs to be compiled by running the asset compiler: `gulp` (named Laravel Elixir docs/5.3/elixir) in Laravel 5.3).

If you followed carefully this part of the tutorials, you shall be extra careful with laravel's npm dependencies versions, specially those used by Elixir (Once again, my gulp installation wasn't working at all even though no error messages showed up).

So, if this is a new project, you should consider updating to Laravel 5.4. If you can't or not willing to update all Laravel framework, perhaps this can be solved like I did. Staying at 5.3 but using the latest assets compiler on 5.4, named [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix). Now it runs on npm: `npm run dev`. (No gulp mentioned on doc.)

**To achieve this**, you should **update** to [latest package.json on 5.4](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.4.9/package.json) and **follow** the 5.4 documentation to install Laravel Mix.

Comment: thanks for your answer @alecuys actually i already fixed it, the problem was, i actually loaded my 'js/app.js' script at the bottom of my page and i trying to get the functionality of echo instance before the actual script load  :P

Answer (score 0):

Your codes looks fine, Problem is your JS order so only you getting undefined issues

like

```
<script>
Echo.channel('TestPusher')
    .listen('TestPusher', (e) => {
        console.log(e.msg, e.chatMessage);
    });
</script>


<script src="echo.js"></script>
```

so zigzag the order :)

Comment: thanks @kali Dass i solved it and yes the problem with my js order

Answer (score 0):

widow object before each Echo.

```
window.Echo.channel('TestPusher')
    .listen('TestPusher', (e) => {
        console.log(e.msg, e.chatMessage);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

remove defer from your app.js script tag

```
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```