# Error Echo is not Defined

Tags: laravel-echo, pusher-js

I'm using pusher and have been trying to configure Laravel Echo as guided in the docs. I have added the following code to `bootstrap.js`

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '###key###',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: true
});
```

After compiling and running the code and I try to use Echo to subscribe to a channel, I get the console error that `Echo is not defined`.

I suspect that when Laravel Mix (5.4) is compiling the assets, it is not including bootstrap.js where Echo is defined. To confirm this, I check the contents of the compiled `app.js` and sure enough, the content from the `bootstrap.js` file are not there.

So, how do I ensure that `bootstrap.js` is also compiled, or how do I go about all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detected why `bootstrap.js` was not being compiled together with the rest of the code. I will write it here because it may be benefit someone else.

The problem was that in the process of making edits to `app.js`, I had removed the line `require('./bootstrap')`, which is the line that imports `bootstrap.js` (probably I thought it is meant to include Twitter Bootstrap).

Just that. It now works well. HTH!

Comment: Hello, Im a beginner and trying to explore more about Laravel. Do you have to put Echo lines to an external or custom js? Or do you put it in the bootstrap.js?

Comment: As per the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting), you ought to put it in bootstrap.js